# Disk errors when booting, system doesn't run properly after disk check

Tags: 11.04, laptop, disk, tmp

I'm using 11.04 on Dell Vostro 1000 laptop. For some time it was ok, but now Ubuntu usually fails to boot.

1. After selecting Ubuntu in grub, I usually see purple (plain, without logo) or black screen for *some minutes* until the login screen appears. I normally chose the user and type my password. Then, I see the default wallpaper (although I had changed it), that is left from login screen and, after about 1 minute the dash and the top panel appears. The wallpaper is still default, the dash is working, but very slowly, or maybe not everything is working, the panel, or only applets, isn't working. (I see ubuntu is trying to paint the effects of pressing an applet, but nothing more is happening). Finally the screen becomes black with a small square on the bottom right corner. I turn off the computer. Then:
2. I turn it on, choose ubuntu, after some time I see that my disk is being checked for errors. Then I get an suggestion to press 'f' and fix the errors. So I press, then wait for some time (The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present), my computer is restarting and everything is working perfectly except the only username is showed in login screen and I have to type mine. However, the next time I turn on the computer, I get the first variant (or at least something very similar).

This has repeated several times - actually ubuntu becomes useless with a such error.

Do you have any suggestions how it would be possible to fix this error?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Live CD/DVD to boot into. While doing that use "Disk Utility" and repair the errors.

This cannot be done on a system while having the disk mounted.

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2010/06/ubuntu-1004-disk-utility-tools_28.html

the reference above is for 10.04 but is relevant for 11.04